# Extend object with properties from another object

Tags: sapui5

I want to extend Combobox and Multicombobox with a new custom property. I know, I can do it with metadata like this:

```
sap.ui.define([
    "sap/m/MultiComboBox"
], function(MultiComboBox) {
    var Box = MultiComboBox.extend("U9.MultiComboBox",{
        metadata: {
            properties: {
                filterType: {
                    type: "string",
                    defaultValue: "default"
                },  ...
```

And for Combobox:

```
sap.ui.define([
    "sap/m/ComboBox"
], function(ComboBox) {
    var Box = ComboBox.extend("U9.ComboBox",{
        metadata: {
            properties: {
                filterType: {
                    type: "string",
                    defaultValue: "default"
                },  ...
```

As I am very lazy person and as I have many custom properties, I do not want to repeat myself, so I would like to create a separate object, and extend combobox with the properties from this object. Might look like this:

```
sap.ui.define([
    "sap/ui/base/ManagedObject"
], function(MO) {
    var Filterable = MO.extend("U9.Filterable",{
        metadata: {
            properties: {
                filterType: {
                    type: "string",
                    defaultValue: "default"
                },  ...

sap.ui.define([
    "sap/m/ComboBox","U9/Filterable"
], function(ComboBox,Filterable) {
    var Box = ComboBox.extend("U9.ComboBox",Filterable...
```

Is it possible to get something like this working? 
I have vague idea that I can override a constructor and add some extra coding there. Do you know if it will work? Is there any examples in openUI5 source I can use?